# $ Inside of OPENQUERY SELECT Statement

Tags: sql-server

My linked server query works fine.  All I need to do is to print a dollar sign ($) in front of the rack rate.  How would I format that?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (TITAN_RICHARDSON, 'SELECT HotelName, RoomType, /*Print $ here*/ RoomRackRate FROM THAI_HOBS.dbo.Hotels H, THAI_HOBS.dbo.Rooms R WHERE H.HotelNo = R.HotelNo')
```

Also, if I wanted to do some type of math (SUM, AVG) or CAST or CONVERT, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT HotelName, RoomType,     CONCAT ('$', RoomRackRate) FROM THAI_HOBS.dbo.Hotels H,     THAI_HOBS.dbo.Rooms R WHERE H.HotelNo = R.HotelNo;
```

for sum

```
 SELECT HotelName, RoomType,     CONCAT ('$', SUM(RoomRackRate)) FROM THAI_HOBS.dbo.Hotels H,     THAI_HOBS.dbo.Rooms R WHERE H.HotelNo = R.HotelNo;
```

Similarly use other math functions.

Comment: Thank you, @xCodeZone!  Unfortunately though, I have to use OPENQUERY format.  :(

Comment: Have you tried adding CONCAT ('$', SUM(RoomRackRate)) to the inner query?

Comment: Yes, the SUM() works, but the single quotes in CONCAT mess with the other single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- double quote the $ sign
 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENQUERY (TITAN_RICHARDSON, 
                 'SELECT  HotelName
                       ,  RoomType
                       ,  CONCAT (''$'', RoomRackRate)
                  FROM    THAI_HOBS.dbo.Hotels H
                       ,  THAI_HOBS.dbo.Rooms R 
                  WHERE   H.HotelNo = R.HotelNo'
                  );
```